# Responsive website showing different on small browser window and iphone

Tags: iphone, responsive-design

I am experiencing a problem while doing research on responsive design.

Most of the responsive sites I am viewing show up the same on iphone and when the browser window is small.

But Paypal.com in a very small browser window (to simulate iphone) does not look the same as the website on the iphone, which seems to be responsive. (Screenshot links provided below).

Can anyone explain why they are viewing differently?

Screenshot on small browser window: http://i1068.photobucket.com/albums/u450/vs-works/paypal-on-iphone_zps0ad2f164.png

Screenshot on iphone: http://i1068.photobucket.com/albums/u450/vs-works/paypal-smallbrowserwindow_zps968aa79f.png

Answer (score 0):

They could be doing two things.

1) sending different html depending on the user agent 
**or**
2) redirecting to a mobile site

Either way they are detecting the client somehow ( likely by reading the user agent string ) and then serving the content accordingly.

What you are used to is responsive design using a liquid layout and css media queries.

Comment: Isn't it "better" to use a liquid layout and css media queries for the most part (i.e. Bootstrap)? I know in that way they can serve device specific functionalities, but it seems most website are not using user agent strings anymore. In paypal's case I think they are using user agent string (#1 as you mentioned), because the url is not different or mobile specific.

Comment: It's definitely easier to develop and maintain a single code base. However you could serve browser/app/device specific content using the user agent string. Each method has it's merits.  For a company the size of Paypal there are other things to consider especially around regulations on what content has to be presented ( legally ) and how branding works. So it might be better for them to have different sites for different devices.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely easier to develop and maintain a single code base. However you could serve browser/app/device specific content using the user agent string. Each method has it's merits.

For a company the size of Paypal there are other things to consider especially around regulations on what content has to be presented ( legally ) and how branding works. So it might be better for them to have different sites for different devices.